# Python speech_recognition pyaudio error

Tags: python, anaconda

I am writing a python code to detect my microphone but speech_recognition is not able to detect my Input device.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
mic_index = 11
    for index, name in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
        if("USB Device" in name):
            mic_index = index
            break
```

But it gives me error. So I checked my `Speech Recognition` module by running the command `python -m speech_recognition` and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/arqam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/arqam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/arqam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/speech_recognition/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    m = sr.Microphone()
  File "/home/arqam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 86, in __init__
    device_info = audio.get_device_info_by_index(device_index) if device_index is not None else audio.get_default_input_device_info()
  File "/home/arqam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 949, in get_default_input_device_info
    device_index = pa.get_default_input_device()
OSError: No Default Input Device Available
```

I checked my IO devices number and pyAudio file location and it gave the following location:

```
>>> pa.get_device_count()
0
>>> pyaudio.pa.__file__
'/home/arqam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_portaudio.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
```

I have seen all the stackoverflow answer and have spent a full day for this problem but still could not find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also had got the same error. Your speech recognition module might not have downloaded properly. To fix that you should search on Google, 'Unofficial Python Binaries'. Click on the first link. The you will see a webpage that contains a lot of python module .wheel files. The find pyaudio link using 'ctrl+f'. On clicking on it you will go to a bunch of pyaudio files. Then you need to find the wheel file that supports your python version. Install it. Then open the folder where you saved that wheel file. Open a powershell or cmd window there and write pip install (name of the wheel file). Then you pyaudio will get downloaded and it should start working!

Answer (score -1):

*The following solved the problem for me.*

*With Anaconda:*

install `speechrecognition` class as well as `pyaudio`

Furhter make sure your microphone is active and check you audio input
device.

Use this simple code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

# obtain audio from the microphone r = sr.Recognizer() with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    enter code here
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print('You said: {}'.format(text))
    except:
        print('Sorry google could not recognize your voice')
```